Funds were not returned after delegation
I stopped delegating in February. But after the delegation ended, my 550 coins were not returned to my balance.
https://tzkt.io/tz1gFvks55KdTekFKuxc8PppsS9LNLuap6Pk/operations/

I dont see my balance in galleon wallet


Stack exchange's AI bot flagged your post below for review. You posted an answer to your own question, instead of a reply to Raphael, he will not be notified of this response as it was sent back to yourself instead of him. Your response was automatically converted to an edit on your question. If you would like to ask Raphael a question, please add a comment to his answer

if your tezos are locked in a KT1 delegation contract (thanks to galleon abandoning ship) :

find your delegation contract address on https://tzkt.io :


go to your manager address list of operation
search for "to created delegator contract KT1"
mouse over the KT1 address and copy it for later


load your galleon wallet with umami wallet (from seed or file as you were doing with galleon) or any other web3 wallet should work

browse to  https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1.../interact/do   =>replace KT1... with your KT1 address

click on the wallet logo top right, chose mainnet then umami (or your other web3 wallet) then allow better call dev in umami (or your other web3 wallet)

back to better call dev page you should see an avatar top right & your manager address when clicking it

if you're not on interact tab of your delegation contract browse to it (paste your KT1 in the search input, browse to it, click on interact



left side, Entry point chose do
empty checked :
in the do input, paste :


{ DROP ;
 NIL operation ;
 PUSH key_hash "tz1..." ;
 IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT ;
 PUSH mutez 100000000 ;
 UNIT ;
 TRANSFER_TOKENS ;
 CONS }


replace tz1... with your manager address
replace 100000000 with desired amount - NB: 100000000 === 100 XTZ !!!

under optional / settings


set source and sender to your manager address (click on fill)
set amount to 0


click on execute then simulate, if the simulation fails you probably have an error somewhere (check your amount in the do is no more than what you have locked and that you have some xtz to pay the fee in the manager address) otherwise you should see the details of the tx with an internal transaction sending back the tezos to your manager account.

If simulation is successful, click on execute then wallet, then allow the tx to be broadcasted in your web3 wallet.


done !
(& to pay me a beer for having helped you unlock your coins => tz1ZK9e1ehUvAnNtpuuWBjGmq5ZoQC812W51 cheers !)

When you delegate your account to some delegate, funds never leave your wallet so there is nothing to return once delegation is stopped.
Your funds are on a smart contract of yours at the following address: "KT1PwcMZJd1jsPS4QwXPepnXRmxKR3j2cp6c".
You seem to be using the Galleon wallet, I am not familiar with it but if this is the wallet which created the account it is probably able to send transactions from it.

Looks like the user created a managed account, which isn't common anymore and not supported by a lot of wallets. Perhaps an explanation of the differences and how to migrate their funds to a more modern setup would be beneficial

Maybe. Pls help:)

@ecehuh maybe ask the question in the cryptonomic forum (makers of galleon) here: https://discourse.cryptonomic.tech/ . There is a process to "withdraw" the funds, but i'm not familiar with Galleon so I can't help with how to do this. FYI, please note that this process has become massively more simple. You no longer need to create a KT1 address, and all the funds stay in your account while delegating, accessible at any time
